# Attaching object without using attach() or with()

Tags: r

This may appear as a strange request, but I'm looking to essentially attach an object temporarily so that individual elements can be extracted from said object, but without actually using `attach()` or `with()`. For instance, I'm well aware that these two approaches are fine to index a `data.frame` elements by name"

```
obj <- data.frame(N=2, sd=1)

myfun <- function(obj){
    N2 <- obj$N^2
    rnorm(N2, obj$sd)
}
myfun(obj)

myfun2 <- function(obj){
    with(obj, {
        N2 <- N^2
        rnorm(N2, sd)
    })
}
myfun2(obj)
```

However, what I want is something more general, where the form can be

```
# wanted
myfun3 <- function(){
    N2 <- N^2
    rnorm(N2, sd)
}
with(obj, myfun3()) #this is the idea but clearly doesn't work
```

so that explicitly indexing the elements of `obj` is not required, and wrapping the whole statement in a `with()` function can be avoided. Obviously `myfun3()` doesn't locate the internals of `obj`, but I would like it to. The following works fine and is exactly what I want from a functional standpoint, but is far from kosher:

```
attach(obj)
myfun3()
detach(obj)
```

Attaching is generally considered bad, and for my purpose this code has to work within an R package, so `attach()` isn't even allowed (as well, it be nested within another function which can be run in parallel....so exporting to the Global Environment likely is not a good solution).

Ultimately, I would like this all to work as follows in a safe parallel computing environment

```
library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster()
parfun <- function(index, obj, myfun){
    out <- with(obj, myfun())
    out
}    
parSapply(cl=cl, 1:100, parfun, obj=obj, myfun=myfun3)
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only thing that confuses me about this is that the title says you don't want to use `with()` but the example of what you want uses `with()`?

Comment: It's conceptual rather than practical. I want something that works like with to make variables accessable, but within a function in a different environment.

Comment: OK. So don't use `with`?

Comment: Yes. If you run the myfun3() blocks you'll see that it doesn't run at all. Only attach works, but it's not a good approach at all. Ultimately it's the last block that I'm after to work.

Comment: OK. Yea I know it doesn't work the way it is in your example but there are several solutions and I'm just trying to figure which one you'll want. For instance you could just delete the `()` and it will run but I figure you don't want that (i.e. `with(obj, myfun3)`).

Comment: You may have a look at `within`. It's sort of an extension of `with` that allows for multiple calls.

Comment: Why? `fortunes::fortune(379)`. "working around" `attach` to accomplish the same thing won't be any more kosher in an R package for CRAN than using `attach` would be. Production code - like functions in packages - should rely on arguments passed to them, not objects that are hopefully present and not overwritten in the global or parent environments.

Comment: @Gregor obviously there's a reason for it (it's not just an academic question). 1) using `debug(myfun)` when all elements are wrapped within a `with()` is essentially useless because all the commands are nested within the same function and can't be stepped through. I would like to avoid the use of explicit `browser()` calls for debugging. 2) Pulling out elements with separate `with(obj, ___)` or $ is both error prone and largely redundant if `obj` can be accessed directly in a manner similar to `attach()`. 3) Avoiding the need for `attach()` because I, and the CRAN maintainers, don't like it.

Comment: *"Avoiding the need for attach() because I, and the CRAN maintainers, don't like it"* - I don't think I understand you here. I don't like `attach`, and I don't see a need for it. I believe the CRAN maintainers feel the same - hence you won't see it used in packages on CRAN. You say you don't like attach either, but you're asking a question that's looking for a function that does the exact same thing as `attach`, but isn't `attach`. Attach by any other name is still attach.

Comment: @Gregor okay, fair point. I'll see if there is an alternative approach which satisfies my wanted criteria. Thanks.

Comment: When you run `R CMD CHECK` on your package, if you have a function like `myfun3` that uses objects that are not either (a) explicitly passed in as arguments or (b) part of the searchable namespace of your package or other packages imported by your package, you will get warnings that your function is using an object without a visible binding. You will get these same warnings whether you are using `attach`, `with`, `subset` or other non-standard evaluating functions (like `dplyr` functions or `ggplot2::aes`).

Comment: This is a reason why functions in Hadley's packages come with standard-evaluating counterparts - `aes_` and `aes_string`, for example. You might want to look into the `lazyeval` package - but when it comes down to it his recommendation is that the standard-evaluating versions of functions are the workhorses, and the NSE versions are light wrappers for non-programmatic convenience. [The main lazyeval vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lazyeval/vignettes/lazyeval.html) is good read, as is the [NSE section of Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html).

Comment: @Gregor yes, but this actually isn't going to be defined by me. The functions are actually user defined and passed to an alternative function for use later. Hence, I won't even know what obj will be in any given call. Lazyeval might be what I need though, thanks for the tip.

Comment: And, not to beat a dead horse, but *" an alternative approach which satisfies my wanted criteria"* - `attach` looks like it nails your stated criteria. You might need to rethink your criteria.

Comment: @Gregor `attach` is widely regarded as a worst practice in R programming with good cause...

Comment: `myfun3 <- function(data){
  eval(N2<-(data$N)^2, parent.frame());
  eval(rnorm(N2, data$sd), parent.frame())
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
do.with  <-  function(context,fun,args=list()){
    env  <-  as.environment(context)
    parent.env(env)  <-  environment(fun)
    environment(fun)  <- env
    do.call(fun,args)
}

context = list(x=1,y=2)
add = function() x + y
do.with(context,add)


context = list(x=2)
parameters = list(y=5)
mult = function(y) x * y
do.with(context,mult,parameters)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!